# Using Google directions API

Tags: java, android, google-directions-api

I am new to JAVA and the android studio ide platform and I need some assistance with using the google directions API.

I have a general idea but I don't know how to implement it in code. At the moment my app has a particular screen that shows a map fragment, a search bar, and button to move the map camera to the searched location. There are some basic permission checks as well and two other items related to another function of the app(at the moment I am focused on being able to use the direction API)

Below is the code I have for that screen related to the map, it would be a great help if someone can help me out with this problem. 
(https://github.com/davidR01/EVDASH1.0.0)

```
public class MainDASH extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

ImageView imageView_Battery;////////////////////////////////////////
TextView textView_Battery;/////////////////////////////////////////

Handler handler;///////////////////////////////////////////
Runnable runnable;///////////////////////////////////////


GoogleMap dashGoogleMap;  /// create google map variable
private final static int MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION = 101; //required to point to which runtime permissions to access


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  // creates the main activity screen
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_dash);
    this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);  /// sets the orientation of the app to landscape at runtime reguagrdless if screen rotation is enabled
    if (googleServicesAvaliable()) {///the map requires play services this call the function to checks to see if it is avaliable
        Toast.makeText(this, "Checking for play_services", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  /// if it is avaliable a message is diplayed this is for testing purposes
    }
    initMap();
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        imageView_Battery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_Battery);///////////////////
        textView_Battery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_Battery);///////////////////////

```
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            int level = (int) batterylevel();

            textView_Battery.setText("BATTERY: " + level + "%");

            if (level > 75) {
                imageView_Battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery_full);
            }

            if (level > 50 && level <= 75) {
                imageView_Battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery_eighty);
            }

            if (level > 25 && level <= 50) {
                imageView_Battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery_fifty);
            }

            if (level <= 25) {
                imageView_Battery.setImageResource(R.drawable.battery_twentyfive);
            }

            handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);
        }
    };

    handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, 0);
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    }

```
private void initMap() {  ////initializes the map fragmant
    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}


public void onButtonClick(View v) {     ////Gives functionality to  the diagnostic button on the home screen
    if (v.getId() == R.id.DiagnosticButton) ;

    Intent i = new Intent(MainDASH.this, loginTSO.class);  //when click goes to the login screen
    startActivity(i);
}


public boolean googleServicesAvaliable() {   // method to check for Google play services
    GoogleApiAvailability api = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(); // gets instance of google api avaliability
    int isAvaliable = api.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvaliable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {  // if it is avaliable return true
        return true;
    } else if (api.isUserResolvableError(isAvaliable)) { // if not avaliable display an error dialog in the form of a popup msg
        Dialog dialog = api.getErrorDialog(this, isAvaliable, 0);
        dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot connect to play services", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); // display message if cannot connect to google play services
    }
    return false;

}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    dashGoogleMap = googleMap;    ////// links the variable created to the google map
    goToLocationZoom(10.6918, -61.2225, 9);  ///////////// calls the gotolocationZoom function that take co-ordinates and moves the camera to that location at the zoom level set
    dashGoogleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);  // changes the default map type to hybrid


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        // TODO: Consider calling
        //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
        // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
        //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
        //                                          int[] grantResults)
        // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
        // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
        dashGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION);
        }

    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case MY_PERMISSION_FINE_LOCATION:

            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    dashGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The MAP requires Location Permissions to be granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            break;
    }
}


private void goToLocation(double latitude, double longitude) {
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ll);
    dashGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
}


private void goToLocationZoom(double latitude, double longitude, float zoom)//zooms in to the set  coordinates in map view
{
    LatLng ll = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(ll, zoom);
    dashGoogleMap.moveCamera(update);
}

public void geoLocate(View view) throws IOException {
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtSearchLocation);
    String location = et.getText().toString();  /// what user enters as string

    Geocoder geocode = new Geocoder(this); //takes any string and converts into latitude and long
    List<Address> list = geocode.getFromLocationName(location, 1);

    Address address = list.get(0);

    String locality = address.getLocality();
    Toast.makeText(this, locality, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    double latitude = address.getLatitude();
    double longitude = address.getLongitude();

    goToLocationZoom(latitude, longitude, 13);

}`
```

Comment: Whats your problem? I cant find anything written in the question that describes a problem. What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: I need to add a function to enter a location and plot a route basically a navigation function and i have no idea how to implement it as I'm a new programmer.

Comment: use the google maps api to get driving directions, then plot them on the map using shapes